# Regex on pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, regex

pandas column has `0.0(nan)` and `0(nan)`. I want to get `0` for both cases. Followed is the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col1': ['0.0(nan)','0(nan)']})
df['col2'] = df['col1'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: re.sub('(.*?)\(nan\)', '\\1', re.sub('(.*?)\.0*\(nan\)', '\\1', x)))
print(df)
```

Below is the output. For the regex, I didn't know how to deal with either `.0` or `0` before the (. This is why I used `re.sub` inside another `re.sub`. My question is how to make the regex in `one re.sub`. Or any other methods? Thank you.

```
       col1 col2
0  0.0(nan)    0
1    0(nan)    0
```

**Edit:** by the comment of @mozway

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: re.sub('(.*?)(?:\.0)?\(nan\)', '\\1', x))
```

Comment: Use `0(?:\.0)?\(nan\)` to match both

Comment: To extract: `str.extract('(\d+)(?:\.0)?\(nan\)')`